# Creating a color hue like snapchat

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a color hue in swift. I researched the allover stackoverflow, I found some examples but they are have 3-4 bars for color pick. I want to create a color picker have one bar. Like snapchat. You can see in the screenshot:

[image]

How can I create a bar like this? I am not asking full code. You can give me a roadmap or little example code etc.

Comment: If you are looking for an easy way it could be done by drawing UIView subviews in the main UIView with color backgrounds and value of rgb varying proportionality with y value of subviews frame

Comment: You can make an image only needs to be 1px in width in photoshop or something.

Comment: @Arbitur Can you explain more?

Comment: make the colored image in photoshop

Comment: Then how can I pick color from this image?

Comment: You can get color rgba from a point in an image

Comment: Hmm, thank you I will research this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics Think this will help you.